# Why is this code not compiling?

Tags: c#

I am getting these errors with this code in the function Doit (I am running .Net 3.5):

Error   1:  `The best overloaded method match for 'LoadPref<A>(string, System.Func<string,A>, A)' has some invalid arguments`
Error   2:  `Argument '2': cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Func<string,A>'`

```
class A : SomeObject
{

}

static class Utilities
{
    private T LoadPref<T>( string key, Func<string, T> loaderFunc, T defaultValue ) 
    {        
       if ( Prefs.HasKey( key ) )
       {
           return loaderFunc( Prefs.GetString( key ) );
       }

       return defaultValue;
    }


    private T LoadAsset<T>( string assetPath ) where T : SomeObject
    {
       return (T)LoadAssetInSomeWay( assetPath );
    }


    private void Doit()
    {
         A asset = LoadPref<A>( "key", LoadAsset, null );
    }
}
```

Anybody knows what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change `LoadAsset` to `LoadAsset<A>` for the generics to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

static class can't contain instance methods.

Comment: Nice catch. I totally missed it.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `LoadPref<A>`, pass in `LoadAsset<A>` instead of just `LoadAsset`.